# PDO query weird behaviour when having multiple queries

Tags: php, database, pdo

I have a class `class db {...}` which I have been using regularly to query my database but for whatever reason the following error occurs.

When querying the previous query influences the next one if the `->results()` or `->count()` is not called.

**Example**

```
$query1 = db::getInstance()->query("do the query");
$query2 = db::getInstance()->query("do the query")->results();
```

If I then call `$query1->results()`, I get the wrong output... Then to verify that the query is influencing the other one I just deleted it and rerun the code and got the correct results (visa versa).

**My DB class (parts used in this case)**

```
class db {
 private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_query,
            $_error = false,
            $_result,
            $_lastinserted = false,
            $_count = 0;

    private function __construct() {
        try {
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . Config::get('mysql/host') . ';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)) {
            self::$_instance = new db();
        }

        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()) {
        $this->_error = false;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
            $x = 1;
            if(count($params)){
                foreach($params as $param){
                    $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                    $x++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
                $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
                $this->_lastinserted = $this->_pdo->lastInsertId();
            } else {
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because you only have a single instance, so you only have one count property and one results property that is the same for your $query1 and $query2, they're both pointing to that same singleton instance

Comment: What you should really have is getInstance returning a new instance (not a singleton) but sharing the _pdo property

Comment: @MarkBaker That is not how I expected it worked. I thought that byp new PDO etc it created a new instance and therefore everything resets. How do you suggest to remake the getInstance function?

Comment: You're creating a new PDO object, but then you're returning the old instance with the old PDO object. I don't see why you need `getInstance`, you should just use `new db`.

Comment: @Barmar I think it was to do with the amount of times it actually connects to the database. When I now query a few times it only access the database 1 time (?).

Comment: You should use prepared statements. Each statement keeps its own state.

Comment: @Barmar And what would be the best way to do that you think?

Comment: Create a singleton DB class that just creates one `new PDO` connection. And a `query` class that uses the `DB` class to call `prepare()` and puts the resulting statement in a property.

Comment: @Barmar i'm sorry but how do I create such a class? can you give an example as the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to design the whole thing here. Maybe you should use an existing framework if you don't know how to design it yourself. Or don't use a class at all, just call PDO functions directly. I don't really get the obsession with hiding this stuff in classes.